# Форматирование BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Всем привет! Необходимо отформатировать число **BigDecimal** следующим образом:

1. **12 300** отформатировать в **12,3 тыс.**
2. **12 300 000** отформатировать в **12,3 млн.**

И так далее. Есть ли какой эффективный способ это сделать средствами java/kotlin?

**P.S:** Я просто подставляю окончание тыс. или млн. в зависимости от форматируемого числа.
**P.S.S:** Данное форматирование буду использовать в Android проекте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Formatter {
    private static final BigDecimal HUNDRED = new BigDecimal("100");
    private static final BigDecimal THOUSAND = new BigDecimal("1000");
    private static final BigDecimal MILLION = new BigDecimal("1000000");
    private static final BigDecimal BILLION = new BigDecimal("1000000000");

    public static String format(BigDecimal value) {
        if (value.compareTo(BILLION) > 0) {
            return String.format("%.1f млрд.", value.divide(BILLION));
        }
        else if (value.compareTo(MILLION) > 0) {
            return String.format("%.1f млн.", value.divide(MILLION));
        }
        else if (value.compareTo(THOUSAND) > 0) {
            return String.format("%.1f тыс.", value.divide(THOUSAND));
        }
        else if (value.compareTo(HUNDRED) > 0) {
            return String.format("%.1f сот.", value.divide(HUNDRED));
        }
        else {
            return String.format("%.1f", value);
        }
    }
}
```